# I am using App links for deeplinks, it works as expected on an emulator but doesnt open in app on a physical device

Tags: android, applinks, android-app-links

clicking on https://myapp.com takes me to the activity its tied to on an emulator when the app is installed. But the same case doesnt work on a physical device. It takes me to the webpage even though the app is installed.
The emulators I used were on Android version 10 and 11, and physical device used for testing was S9 (android 10) and Pixel 6 (android 12)

Answer (score 0):

I had autoVerify set to true, so to test on physical devices I needed to have a signed build.

Comment: I have signed the release build, but still facing this problem.
I tried debug and release: both works on the emulator, but not on the device.
Do you have any idea why?